# Most efficient way to track execution time of methods in REST API? (Java Spring Boot app, Swagger)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, execution-time

I have a Java Spring Boot API (Swagger) that I is having thousands of calls on it daily. I wanted to log the execution times of these methods for analysis. I used Spring AOP (Aspect Orientated Programming) to make a simple interface and concrete class that allows me to annotate my methods with @TrackExecutionTime to see the runtime. I have listed the code for that below. My problem is, that in the logs, I am tracking the method call times, but I have thousands of requests, so I need a way of "tagging" each api call and logging it, so I can follow the flow of each api call. I was thinking of generating a random # or maybe someone here had a better suggestion. So the logging currently looks like this:
`"com.mypackage.myclassname.mymethodname. Time taken for Execution is : 100ms"`

Also, My first RestController uses Swagger, so I tried to annotate the method with my @TrackTimeExecution, but we are using the **swagger-codegen-maven** plugin, so it reads the swagger definition yaml file and generates the "CustomerApi" and other classes/interfaces when it compiles. When I tried annotating at the class level per below, the Spring Boot app compiles, but when I run the app locally on port 8080 and try to hit the endpoint I annotated with Postman, nothing happens at all. It's like annotating breaks the swagger codegen or something, so I had to settle with sticking the annotation on the customersService.getCustomers() method. Is this acceptable? I figured I would need to clock the execution from when the Controller first gets hit, but as I said,  I coudln't do it this way unless I'm making some dumb mistake, so I had to put it on the *next* method the controller calls. Does this make my timing of the api call inaccurate since I would need to time in when the app first gets the request by the controller? Would love any input here...

Dumbed dumb implementation of one of my endpoints, basically the same:

```
@RestController
@TrackExecutionTime // this fails to compile
public class CustomerApiController implements CustomerApi {
    @Autowired
    public CustomerApiController(ObjectMapper objectMapper, HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.request = request;
}

public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> searchCustomer() {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>(this.customerService.getCustomers(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Class that logs the execution time of any method annotated with "@TrackExecutionTime"

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnExpression("${aspect.enabled:true}")
public class ExecutionTimeAdvice {

    @Around("@annotation(com.mailshine.springboot.aop.aspectj.advise.TrackExecutionTime)")
    public Object executionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object object = point.proceed();
        long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Class Name: "+ point.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() +". Method Name: "+ point.getSignature().getName() + ". Time taken for Execution is : " + (endtime-startTime) +"ms");
        return object;
    }
}
```

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrackExecutionTime {
}
```

Comment: Isn't [spring mv metrics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-spring-mvc) something what you are searching for?

Comment: `When I tried annotating at the class level per below, the app failed to compile..` - Did the application startup failed with an exception about , cannot subclass a final class ?

Comment: @bilak I'll checkout spring metrics, I thought Spring AOP was the solution

Comment: @R.G I update my post. The spring boot app compiles fine and boots up on localhost:8080. The problem is when I try to hit the endpoint that I annotated, nothing happens , I get a 404 NOT FOUND from postman. It's like adding the annotation breaks the API because we are using Swagger code gen

Answer (score 0):

To use this annotation over class you have to change target of the annotation to ElementType.TYPE instead of ElementType.METHOD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring aop and aspectj to get the execution time but if the class has not interface then remember to add @EnableAspectJAutoProxy (proxyTargetClass = true) annotation it's a CGLIB. But if you are sure that your service is not having class without interface then go ahead no need to add that annotation.
If you have final class then the proxy is not going to be created you will get error (Common causes of this problem include using a final class.) or if you have private constructor only. And if the flow is going to final method, then it will not get intercept and you will get NullPointerException and the aplication will break.